# ON creating BITMAP INDEX on a table in mysql throws error

Tags: mysql, sql

say, i have database named "demo_dev" database and added a table named "countries".

i wanted to create bitmap index on a column say region as it has less unique values using following query.

```
 CREATE BITMAP INDEX ON countries (region);
```

it throwed an error as shown below:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BITMAP INDEX ON countries (region)'

what shoud be done to run it successfully.

i just refered the following link : http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=1524

Comment: That's from the "wishlist" and not implemented yet.

Comment: ok, can i perform cluster index instead of bitmap index then

Comment: If you're using the InnoDB storage engine, you could.